# ReactJs not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am a little confused as to why this function of mine will not update the state like it should. I get a date object, then convert it to the format I would like it in, but when I try and set the state at the very bottom, the callback alert is just blank.

How can I make it so the state updates as soon as this function is over?

```
floorLastCleanedChange(date) {
    this.setState({ flooringLastCleanedTest: date });
    var floorDate = new Date(date);
    alert(floorDate);
    var day = floorDate.getDate();
    if(day.toString().length === 1)
    {
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    var month = floorDate.getMonth() + 1;
    if(month.toString().length === 1)
    {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    var year = floorDate.getFullYear();
    alert(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
    this.setState({flooringLastCleaned: month+"/"+day+"/"+year}, alert(this.state.flooringLastCleaned));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. The callback to setState is only a `function`, you were making a `function call` instead in your code in the callback.

```
setState(
  {flooringLastCleaned: month+"/"+day+"/"+year},
  () => alert(this.state.flooringLastCleaned);
);
```

Comment: Well that did the trick! I guess I didn't quite understand what the callback needed exactly. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @PushedCrayon Good answer. regarding your comment, you need to pass a function definition as a callback without calling it, which is later called (when the state is updated). In your code you were calling alert right away, instead of passing it.